# Byte array transferring through socket

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, byte

I am trying to send a simple byte array using Socket in a client-server architecture. There are problems also in debugging with Netbeans because it gives:

> SocketException: connection reset

So I post below my code and I would really like if someone helps me.

Client:

```
public class TestClient {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3242);     

        byte[] b;
        b = "Hello".getBytes();
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        os.write(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Server:

```
public class TestServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        byte[] b = new byte[5];
        Socket s = new ServerSocket(3242).accept();
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        is.read(b);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

}

I tried to use InputStream and OutputStream simply, but the behaviour is the same.

The result running those codes above is:

```
[B@25154f
```

Thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));
```

With this:

```
System.out.println(new String(b));
```

This will convert your byte array into a `String` using the `default encoding`. It will work if both the server and client use the same `default encoding` otherwise you will need to specify the encoding in both side as next:

In `TestClient` `"Hello".getBytes(encoding)`

In `TestServer` `System.out.println(new String(b, encoding))`

Answer (score 0):

Thats because in your case `String.valueOf` takes Object as an input (and treats it as an object).

If you are sure you recive a String, you can call `new String(b)`, or `new String(b, "UTF-8")` instead.

Comment: Now the result is [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]. It is the correct representation of "Hello" in bytes. From this, how can I do to get "Hello" back as String? Thanks. (@NicolasFilotto gave me the way using the String constructor) Thanks again.